# Gridspec spanning fractional column width

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-gridspec

I'd like a plot that has two subplots in the first row, each spanning 1.5 columns, and three plots in the second row, each a column wide. Is that possible with matplotlib and gridspec? From the [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#examples-using-matplotlib-gridspec-gridspec), it doesn't appear to be so. The `width_ratios` argument also won't work since that affects all rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
gs = GridSpec(2, 3)

# First row (1.5 column width)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1])

# Second row (one-third width)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 2])

ax1.set_title('Subplot 1')
ax2.set_title('Subplot 2')
ax3.set_title('Subplot 3')
ax4.set_title('Subplot 4')
ax5.set_title('Subplot 5')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The code above produces this. I just can't figure out how to make subplots 1 and 2 span 1.5 columns.

[image: incorrect spacing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html):

```
axd = plt.figure(layout='constrained', figsize=(10,6)).subplot_mosaic(
    """
    AAABBB
    CCDDEE
    """
)
for i, ax in enumerate(axd.values(), start=1):
    ax.set_title(f'Subplot {i}')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do a `2x6` grid:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
gs = GridSpec(2, 6)

# First row (1.5 column width)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :3])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 3:])

# Second row (one-third width)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, :2])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 2:4])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 4:])

ax1.set_title('Subplot 1')
ax2.set_title('Subplot 2')
ax3.set_title('Subplot 3')
ax4.set_title('Subplot 4')
ax5.set_title('Subplot 5')


plt.tight_layout()
```

output:

[image]